# Can you SQL replicate tables from a logged-shipped secondary DB to a separate third DB?

Tags: replication, log-shipping

Can you SQL replicate tables from a logged-shipped secondary DB to a separate third DB?

The idea is to offload some long running scripts from those tables, and if possible avoiding touching the primary DB.

I have tried to research this before just jumping straight in and have found very few references as to if this is supported or possible.

Any advice appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Is there anyone out there who has set this up ever in a production environment?

Comment: Does anyone know if this is even supported by MicroSoft. I have checked on their website, but I just can't find a definitive answer as to if it is possible, let alone supported.